# Global Request Filter Async Order of Operations

Tags: c#, servicestack

Where do async global request filters fit in the order of operations as described [here](http://docs.servicestack.net/order-of-operations)?

We recently added a global async filter and a request filter with priority `int.MaxValue` was executed before the the async filter. When we changed the async global request filter to a non-async global request filter, the global request filter was executed before the request filter with priority `int.MaxValue`.

Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

They're executed after the sync Global Request Filters and Request Filter Attributes.

Comment: I would have expected it to happen just before or just after the non-async global request filters. Thanks for the clarification!